# pip keeps reinstalling packages when installed using `--user` flag

Tags: python, pip

I'm using pip to install packages locally `--user`. It works fine except that packages already installed keep getting reinstalled when calling pip again. This doesn't happen with globally `sudo pip` installed packages.

I want to install several packages in my setup script that uses pip, but to avoid the lengthy download/install process when the packages were already installed locally (using the same script).

Is there a way to install packages using pip locally without reinstalling already existing (locally) packages?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by 'install packages locally'? installing in a `virtualenv`?

Comment: @dm295, I mean installing using `--user` flag or simply calling pip without `sudo`.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'already existing (locally) packages'? If I run `pip install --user numpy` twice, the second time pip just prints `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy in ./.local/lib/python3.4/site-packages`

Comment: I see a different behavior. The package (pyzmq) gets downloaded and reinstalled every time I run pip. pip version 1.5.6 python 2.7.9

Comment: Same problem here. Could you figure out the cause yet?